# Исчезновение блока в зависимости от разрешения экрана

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

Нужно сделать, что бы текст не показывался в том случае если разрешение, к примеру, меньше чем 350x700 пикселей. Возможно ли как-нибудь это сделать на CSS?